# Multiple php versions - how to update php version in Wordpress settings

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu-server

I have a Ubuntu Apache2 server where I have updated PHP to 7.3.

I can see from /etc/php/ PHP-versions from 5.6. to 7.3. installed.

```
php -r "phpinfo();" | grep php.ini
```

Confirms me that the latest version is being used.

However, a Wordpress -website running on the server, is still using the old PHP 7.0. How can I configure Wordpress to use the new version instead? I haven't found the php path defined in any of the wordpress files.

Comment: You can't "configure WordPress" to use the new version. WordPress has nothing to do with that. You need to update your webserver's configuration so that it uses PHP 7.3 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating the php to version 7.3, you should enable that mode in apache configuration.

Run this command:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.3
```

Comment: That was already enabled, but wordpress was still running the old version. However after your a2enmod php7.3: I ran "sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3", whereafter restart apache finally did the trick for WP as well.